# Why is installing a software difficult in Ubuntu than in Windows?

Tags: 12.10

I am new to ubuntu and I am using 12.10 distro.

Why are different commands required to install a sofware, what do these commands do ?

Comment: what "commands" are you referring to? please give examples

Comment: Not only is your question incomprehensible, but 12.10 reached end of life years ago and is no longer supported.

Comment: If you stick to Ubuntu software center you do not even have to leave your home (leave it virtually that is ;) ) since it will download what your ask.

Comment: I think this question is primarily opinion-based..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install applications in Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/307280/how-do-i-install-applications-in-ubuntu)

Comment: I am using 12.10 distro which has reached its end of life. I was a windows user and all the aspects related to Ubuntu are new to me, like EOL. I will switch to latest distro once I get a webpage suggesting the ways to use my USB modem on 14.10 distro, which I am not able to find it now. There are several webpages suggesting the ways to use my USB modem Micromaxx 352g, for 12.10 distro. I am sure that with the passing time I shall see some guidance to use the modem on some latest distro. Thanks and regards to all.

Comment: I have updated the 14.04(the updates were of about 500 MB) and all the softwares are working fast. The first tip to be given to any new Ubuntu user is to install the latest distro available, otherwise one would have to come to askubuntu again and again. Thanks and Regards to all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Installing most softwares on Ubuntu are actually easier than on Windows once you get the hang of it.

Installation of packages can be done via the *Ubuntu Software Center*, a Graphical User Interface based application where installing an application only involves the clicking of the *Install* button.

Alternatively, the Terminal can also be used to install packages using `apt-get`. All you have to do is to open the Terminal and enter the command -

```
sudo apt-get install <packagename>
```

For example, if you want to install VLC Media Player -

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

As you may notice, both the above methods are quite straightforward and do not require the user to navigate through web pages searching for `.exe` or `.msi` files to download and then install by clicking on the *Next* option numerous times, as is the case in Windows.

Comment: I am using ubuntu 12.10
I am getting the following error and vlc is not getting installed.

abhi@abhi-desktop:~$ sudo apt-get install vlc
[sudo] password for abhi: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package vlc
abhi@abhi-desktop:~$

Comment: That is because Ubuntu 12.10 has reached its end of life (EOL) and is no longer supported. Install a newer and supported version like 14.04 or 14.10 instead.

Comment: Oh.. Like Microsoft Windows XP has reached EOL ? EOL is a new term for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Linux and Windows are two different things - and are completely different organized. Linux, Ubuntu in this case is organized in packages. A package is a part of the whole system that has a specific exercise. And also applications are divided in at least one package that can be installed through a so called **package manager**. In Ubuntu and other derivatives this is **apt-get**, or you can use a gui called **synaptic**.

Every packet has a name to identify, and can be installed with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install your_package_name
```

For example, to install Skype type:

```
sudo apt-get install skype
```

And to remove a packet, type `remove` instead of `install`.

To see all commands/operants open the terminal and type

```
apt-get --help
```

Comment: What do you call that 'dash sign', between apt and get? Is it called 'minus' or simply 'dash'? I am new to ubuntu. Regards.

Comment: Is there a difference? I don't know, but that is a simple minus sign that you can also type in your numpad.

Answer (score 0):

It not obligatory to use commands. You can do most things with User Interface.But commands are easier, faster ways of installing software and managing your computer in general.

If you want to install software in Ubuntu the easiest way is through **Ubuntu Software Centre**. Go into the Software centre, choose an app you want and click Install button.

Second way to install an app is **Synaptic** Manager.Again choose an app, tick the check button, mark for install and Apply.

If you want to install a software outside  Ubuntu repositories, for example Google chrome, you should download .deb format file for it. After you can install it them through software centre or install it using **Gdebi** .

You can get both Synaptic and Gdebi through software centre.

First of all I strongly recommend to upgrade your Ubuntu to a supported release.

Comment: If I upgrade to Ubuntu 14.04 , do I need to install synaptic package manager, or would it be installed in the distro, by default ?

Comment: By default only Ubuntu Software centre is installed. You will have to install Synaptic or Gdebi by yourself.

Comment: What is the significance of package managers ? What do they do ? (I have searched this question and it is explained in complex terminology)

Comment: They make installing, removing, updating and reinstalling apps easier. Package is an app (If we say it very simple). You can control your packages, that is to say apps with them.

Comment: You can not do *everything* in a GUI.  One of the big reasons the command line will never go away is that there are an infinite number of permutations of commands you can type to do whatever you need done, but there are only so many buttons and menus you can click on.

Comment: @psusi And any GUI attempting to make menus and buttons for it all would be horribly complex.